# Infinite recursion with std::move

Tags: c++, move, rvalue, lvalue

I have a class that mimicks a std::vector.
For this, I want to have a function push_back that accepts both an lvalue and a rvalue.

```
    void push_back(const T& obj) {
        push_back(std::move(obj));
    }

    void push_back(T&& obj) {
        buffer[numElements] = obj;
        numElements = numElements+1>=Sz-1 ? Sz-1 : numElements+1;

    }
```

However, this code ends in an endless recursion when I pass an lvalue due to move, it calls the wrong function (I would expect `const T& obj` function to call `T&& obj` overload).

The doc of std::move says

> It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference type.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's no good way to implement one of the overloads using the other. The first one needs to do `buffer[numElements] = obj;`, and the second one needs to do `buffer[numElements] = std::move(obj);`.

Comment: There is more code in these functions. It would be better to do it my way to reduce code duplication, wouldn't it?

Comment: `buffer[numElements] = obj;` should be `buffer[numElements] = std::move(obj);` (else just have single `push_back(const T&)` ;-) ).

Comment: But that would mean that I can't pass a temporary, right? @Jarod42

Comment: @Raildex Reducing duplication is good, but in this case you can't achieve it by implementing one of the overloads based on the other. Your options are: using a single template function instead (with a forwarding reference parameter, similar to `emplace_back`, as the comment below suggests), or moving the duplicate code to some other hidden function.

Comment: You might still forward to `template <typename U> void push_back_impl(U&&)` to avoid duplication

Comment: @Raildex Whether or not you can pass something depends only on the parameter type, not on what you do with it in the function body. Without `std::move`, the second overload will copy the argument (instead of moving it, which would make more sense).

Comment: temporary binds to const ref, so you can still pass it with single overload (it might be not optimal against the 2 versions). My suggesting fix make your `T&&` overload useful, else it does a copy inside the function instead of a move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue is that, in

```
void push_back(const T& obj) {
    push_back(std::move(obj));
}
```

you got `const T&&` with `std::move`.

So only viable candidate is `void push_back(const T&)`, so infinite recursive call.

Comment: Alright. Thank you! Making `T&& obj` to `const T&& obj` makes it work!

Comment: Having `void push_back(const T&& obj)` overload is nearly pointless has you cannot really steal the resource, as `const`.